# Compare difference between 2 rows at the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with duplicate registers of students, but each row represent a course and a status from that student.

I'm using SQL SERVER 2008

Something like that:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
|   ID   |   STUDENT   |          DATE           |    COURSE     |     STATUS      |
+--------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
|  21245 | ROBERTA ZOR | 2014-01-08 00:00:00.000 | CIÊNCIAS      | FORMADO         |
|  39316 | IGOR BASTOS | 2008-04-07 00:00:00.000 | CIÊNCIAS      | CANCELADO       |
|  39316 | IGOR BASTOS | 2014-01-08 00:00:00.000 | ADMINISTRAÇÃO | FORMADO         |
|  39961 | LUIZ FELIPE | 2014-02-12 00:00:00.000 | ADMINISTRAÇÃO | CURSANDO        |
| 105937 | DANIEL CHO  | 2014-02-14 00:00:00.000 | ADMINISTRAÇÃO | CURSANDO        |
| 105937 | DANIEL CHO  | 2014-02-10 00:00:00.000 | ADMINISTRAÇÃO | RESERVA DE VAGA |
+--------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I need the most recent STATUS from the combination STUDENT/COURSE for all Students.

**UPDATE**

To get the STATUS I'm using another join:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.STUDENT, a.COURSE, MAX(a.DATE) as DATE

into #TABLE
FROM #STUDENTS a
INNER JOIN #STUDENTS b
on a.ID = a.ID
and a.COURSE = b.COURSE
and a.STATUS <> b.STATUS
GROUP BY a.ID,a.STUDENT, a.COURSE


select c.ID, c.STUDENT, c.COURSE, c.STATUS
into #FINAL_TABLE
from #TABLE t
inner join #STUDENTS C
on C.ID = T.ID and C.STUDENT = T.STUDENT and C.COURSE = T.COURSE
```

Comment: I've updated the table.
In the case of Daniel Cho I need the row with CURSANDO STATUS.

Comment: Are you only looking for students who's status within a course has changed, or are you actually looking for the most recent status for each course a student is in?

Comment: @Manjuba, and is that the only row you would want returned from the example data?

Comment: I need one register of each student. If the student have duplicate course, I need only the most recent.

Comment: @Majuba I believe you need to check your selected answer.  1) It will only get you the most recent date for each `STUDENT`/`COURSE` combination.  2) It will filter out courses where all students have only one `STATUS` and it is the same one. 3) It will not get you the most recent `STATUS` (if you try to add it in the `SELECT`/`GROUP`, you will get multiple rows for `STUDENT`/`COURSE` combinations where a student has multiple statuses for a given course.

Comment: @JonSenchyna Both queries return the same number of rows. I've tried to understand exactly what happens in each one, but I can't figure out. SQL has no sense for me :( .

Comment: @JonSenchyna I've updated my question with the query i'm using now.

Comment: @Manjuba Try changing the two rows for the `CIÊNCIAS` course to both have the same `STATUS`, then running the SQL statements.

Comment: I trimmed down my answer to just show what you are asking for. Also, here's a [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37df2/4/1) showing the difference between the two queries, using the method mentioned in my previous comment (note that the second result set is missing two rows):

Comment: Realy, you got me. Daniel Cho is repeated in the #FINAL_TABLE. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will find the most recent row for each Student/Course combination.  It uses a [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to find the most recent date for each `STUDENT`/`COURSE` combination, and then uses that CTE to get the matching rows.  The end result is the most recent row for each `STUDENT`/`COURSE` combination.

```
WITH
CTE_MostRecent AS (
  -- For each student/course combination, retrieve:
  --  * student ID
  --  * course
  --  * date of most recent entry
  SELECT ID,
         COURSE,
         MAX(DATE) AS MaxDate -- Most recent date
  FROM StudentCourses
  GROUP BY ID,
           COURSE
)
SELECT S.*
FROM   StudentCourses AS S
-- Only select the the most recent row
-- for this STUDENT/COURSE combination
INNER JOIN CTE_MostRecent AS M
    ON  S.ID = M.ID
    AND S.COURSE = M.COURSE
    AND S.DATE = M.MaxDate
```

**Output ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd480/28/0)):**

```
╔════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╗
║   ID   ║   STUDENT   ║        DATE         ║    COURSE     ║  STATUS   ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 105937 ║ DANIEL CHO  ║ 2014-02-14 00:00:00 ║ ADMINISTRAÇÃO ║ CURSANDO  ║
║  39961 ║ LUIZ FELIPE ║ 2014-02-12 00:00:00 ║ ADMINISTRAÇÃO ║ CURSANDO  ║
║  39316 ║ IGOR BASTOS ║ 2008-04-07 00:00:00 ║ CIÊNCIAS      ║ CANCELADO ║
║  39316 ║ IGOR BASTOS ║ 2014-01-08 00:00:00 ║ ADMINISTRAÇÃO ║ FORMADO   ║
║  21245 ║ ROBERTA ZOR ║ 2014-01-08 00:00:00 ║ CIÊNCIAS      ║ FORMAD    ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

**Note:** The output above is taken from an actual SQL-Server instance, not from SQLFiddle.  SQLFiddle displays `DATETIME` values as "[MonthName], DD YYYY 14 HH:MM:SS+0000"

**Note:** This solution assumes that you have at most one entry per `STUDENT`/`COURSE` combination per day.

Comment: I need the most recent STATUS from the combination STUDENT/COURSE for all Students.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select * from 
    (select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by COURSE,STATUS order by dates)rn 
     from @student)t4 where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is

```
SELECT a.id, a.student, a.course, MAX(a.date) as hight_date
FROM table  a
INNER JOIN table b on a.course = b.course
WHERE a.status != b.status
GROUP BY  a.id,a.student, a.course
```

Comment: if you want to see the status, add the column in the select and group by

Comment: Your SQL is flawed.  The `INNER JOIN` is only making sure that there are at least two different `STATUS` values for each `COURSE`, regardless of what student they are assigned to.  With the current data, you get the same results by removing it.  If all students in the same `COURSE` have only one `STATUS` value (and it is the same), then you will get no rows for them.

Comment: Your query just happens to get the correct results for this specific set of data.  Try making the two entries for the "CIÊNCIAS" course have the same `STATUS`.  Your query will return no rows for that course.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37df2/2/0

Comment: Also, if you add the status to the `SELECT` and `GROUP` clauses, then you will get one row for each `STATUS`, when the OP specifically wanted only the most recent `STATUS`.

Comment: @Jon Yup, I don't see how this fulfils OPs requirements either, ah well... maybe OP will reconsider once he plays around with it.

Comment: when I answered the question, the request was for the same course and different state.  if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Ganz, yup OP never made it clear about whether it was per student, but he specifically wants the latest status, and this query doesn't return that. Either way, evidently this suited the OP.

Comment: @Ganz Actually, you are mistaken.  The [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21856931/1) of the question stated that the results were to be for "each ID".  Subsequent updates eventually changed it to "students", but they both mean the same thing in this case.

Comment: @JonSenchyna Correct, the first version was: "I ​​need to select where COURSE STATUS are same and are different from each and DATE are higher ID"